# How to add custom TFS CheckinNoteDefinitions?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, git-tfs

Using TFS 2012 client C# API, I can add CheckinNotes to each commit; CheckinNotes need a suitable CheckinNoteFieldDefinition for each CheckinNoteFieldValue, or the checkin will be rejected and an exception is thrown.

How can I add additional (custom) CheckinNoteFieldDefinitions to the tfs server?

I am not really getting any useful information out of the MSDN documentation.

Related MSDN links:

- [CheckinNoteFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.checkinnotefieldvalue.aspx)
- [CheckinNoteFieldDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.checkinnotefielddefinition.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's created dynamically by the server once you check-in with any custom check-in notes:

```
var checkinNoteFieldValues = new[]
{
    new CheckinNoteFieldValue("Custom Note", "some value"),
    new CheckinNoteFieldValue("Other Note", "other value")
};
var checkinNote = new CheckinNote(checkinNoteFieldValues);
var pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges(); // workspace is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace
workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, "comment", checkinNote, null, null); // checkinNote will trigger a new CheckinNoteFieldDefinition
```